# multicolumn display for partial list of table

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have a file with some consecutive tables one for each month. The `listoftables` takes up too much space when it lists each table entry on a separate line. I can use `multicols` to have a two column output for the whole list of tables, however I do not want to do this for all the tables. How can I get, say, three column output in the list of table for certain range of tables?

The output for list of tables I am trying to get to (preferably first one):

```
1.1 Table . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 2
1.2 January . . . 2    1.3 February  . . 2    1.4 March . . . . 2
1.5 April . . . . 3    1.6 May . . . . . 3    1.7 June  . . . . 3
1.8 July  . . . . 3
1.9 More tables . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 3

1.1 More tables from next chapter . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 4
```

or

```
1.1 Table . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 2
1.2 January . . . 2    1.5 April . . . . 3    1.8 July  . . . . 3
1.3 February  . . 2    1.6 May . . . . . 3
1.4 March . . . . 2    1.7 June  . . . . 3
1.9 More tables . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 3

2.1 More tables from next chapter . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 4
```

My current hackish solution using `addtocontents` "almost" works but, other than obvious issues with alignment and dot spacing, it is not flexible if I want to switch between two-, three- or four-column layout. And more importantly it is not automatic.

Also I am not sure how to suppress the list of table entry for particular table. I tried `caption*` with `caption` package but that did not work. I am guessing it has something to do with `memoir` class.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\threecoltab}[3]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX} #1 & #2 & #3 \end{tabularx}}

\newcommand{\spaceddotfill}[0]{{} \dotfill \hspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\lotcontent}[6]{\noindent%
    \hyperref[#2]{#1} \spaceddotfill{} \pageref{#2} \hspace{1em}%
    \hyperref[#4]{#3} \spaceddotfill{} \pageref{#4} \hspace{1em}%
    \hyperref[#6]{#5} \spaceddotfill{} \pageref{#6} \newline}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
% \begin{multicols}{2}  \listoftables   \end{multicols}

\chapter{Records}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{Table}       \label{tab:t1} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{January}     \label{tab:m1} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{February}    \label{tab:m2} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{March}       \label{tab:m3} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{April}       \label{tab:m4} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{May}         \label{tab:m5} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{June}        \label{tab:m6} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{July}        \label{tab:m7} \end{table}

\begin{table}[htp] \caption{More tables} \label{tab:t2} \end{table}

\addtocontents{lot}{\noindent
    \hyperref[tab:m1]{January}  \spaceddotfill{} \pageref{tab:m1} \hspace{1em}
    \hyperref[tab:m2]{February} \spaceddotfill{} \pageref{tab:m2} \hspace{1em}
    \hyperref[tab:m3]{March}    \spaceddotfill{} \pageref{tab:m3} \newline}

\addtocontents{lot}{\lotcontent{January}{tab:m1}{February}{tab:m2}{March}{tab:m3}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\lotcontent{April}{tab:m4}{May}{tab:m5}{June}{tab:m6}}
% \addtocontents{lot}{\lotcontent{July}{tab:m7}{}{}{}{}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\noindent
    \hyperref[tab:m7]{July}  \spaceddotfill{} \pageref{tab:m7} }

%\addtocontents{lot}{\threecoltab{\hyperref[tab:m1]{January}}{\hyperref[tab:m2]{February}}{\hyperref[tab:m3]{March}}}

\chapter{Data}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{Table from next chapter} \label{tab:t3} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}


\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline



%non hyperref version
\def\mcontentsline#1#2#3#4{%
\ifvmode\noindent\else\unskip\hspace{1em plus 2pt}\fi
\hbox{\vbox{\hsize=\dimexpr(\hsize-#1em+1em)/#1\relax
\oldcontentsline{#2}{#3}{#4}}}}

\def\mcontentsline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\ifvmode\noindent\else\unskip\hspace{1em plus 2pt}\fi
\hbox{\vbox{\hsize=\dimexpr(\hsize-#1em+1em)/#1\relax
\oldcontentsline{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}}}

\protected\def\ltcols#1{%
\ifnum#1=1
\par\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\else
\par\def\contentsline{\mcontentsline{#1}}%
\fi}



\begin{document}

\listoftables


\chapter{Records}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{Table}       \label{tab:t1} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \addtocontents{lot}{\ltcols{3}}\caption{January}\label{tab:m1} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{February}    \label{tab:m2} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{March}       \label{tab:m3} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{April}       \label{tab:m4} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{May}         \label{tab:m5} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{June}        \label{tab:m6} \end{table}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{July}        \label{tab:m7} \end{table}


\begin{table}[htp] \addtocontents{lot}{\ltcols{1}}\caption{More tables} \label{tab:t2} \end{table}



\chapter{Data}
\begin{table}[htp] \caption{Table from next chapter} \label{tab:t3} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `memoir` inserts some vertical space in list of tables, when changing chapter, by adding entry `\addvspace{10pt}` to `.lot` file. This causes error when compiling if the list of tables entry is not switched back to `oldcontentsline`. I was able to get around the problem by removing the empty space by specifying `\renewcommand{\insertchapterspace}{}`, as suggested in the manual. To keep the space on can do something like, 
`\renewcommand{\insertchapterspace}{ \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}} \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\ltcols{1}\addvspace{10pt}} }`

Comment: Yes that's why for `1` the definition I gave switches back the definition rather than just using the paragraph version with full width setting. although probably in a real case you would want to switch after the last table in the previous chapter so your addition looks good

Comment: I ran into two issues and need help. 1. If I remove the `hyperref` package, I get an error `Argument of \mcontentsline has an extra }`. This is not a big concern as I mostly use `hyperref`. ''2''. If I do not have enough tables to list in a row then the alignment is off. For example if I comment out the tables for June and July from current example then the table for May is listed in the last column instead of the middle one. I tried playing with the `hfill` argument, but did not get much far.

Comment: fixed to account for the fact that with three columns you have 2 1em spaces rather than 3, also version for no hyperref added (4 arguments rather than 5, just comment out the hyperref (2nd) version of mcontentsline if you remove hyperref and delete the `.lot` file